# unable to run Todo list app in rethinkdb on ubuntu..so can you provide the steps

Tags: python-2.7

When I'm executing `cd/user/share/nginx/html`, I get `No such file or directory`.

Comment: are u sure that is user   or usr

Comment: Are you trying to `cd` to `/user/share/nginx/html`? The command should look like `cd /user/share/nginx/html`, not `cd/user/share/nginx/html`; you need a space after `cd` as it is the command. As you have the command in your question, the terminal is attempting to open the file `html` under `./cd/user/share/nginx/`, which obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You've missed a space between `cd` and the path, and it's `/usr/` not `/user/`

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't understand, there not being a space in the command is a perfectly valid thing to point out. It should also mention the typo in `usr`... But it's not not-an-answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default, nginx is installed at `/usr/share/nginx/html`
[image]